# ios increase/ decrease the size of a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I am new to ios and I have the following issue.

I want to increase and decrease the size of a tableview in height depending the number of elements in the table view. If at input the client gives 3 or more than 3 elements at output i want to see a tableview bigger then 2 lines than the default one. When the number of elements are 2 or 1 at output I will see the default table view height. The width will be the same. How to do this?

Here is my code:

```
if (inputList.count>2)
    {
           CGRect bounds = [self.tableView bounds];
         [self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,
                                        bounds.origin.y,
                                        bounds.size.width,
                                        bounds.size.height + 50)];
         CGRect tableFrame = [ self.predictiveDialog frame];
               tableFrame.size.height=75;
         [self.tableView setFrame:tableFrame];

    }
    else 
    {
         NSLog(@"decrease size");

         [self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,
                                                    bounds.origin.y,
                                                    bounds.size.width,
                                                    bounds.size.height - 50)];
         CGRect tableFrame = [ self.predictiveDialog frame];
         tableFrame.size.height=44;
         [self.tableView setFrame:tableFrame];

    }
```

In this case the tableview width is ok and height is ok when input elements come in, but depending on the no of elements in inputlist - the tableview is moving up and down on the ios Screen . Why?

Comment: You want the frame of the table view to be increased or the height of the cells in the table view?

Comment: I want to increase the height of the tableview.

Comment: Please refer to my answer and set bounds to accordingly. Also what "bounds" in your code referring to? i mean which view. I guess its some other view

Comment: i'VE EDITED MY CODE. I was refering to my tableView bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the **bounds** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` **delegate** method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([indexPath row]>2)
    {

         [tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                        self.tableView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                        self.tableView.frame.size.height + 50)];

    }

  // your other code
}
```

Hope this helps you. Hope i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CGFloat height = self.tableView.rowHeight;
height *= inputList.count;

CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height = height;
self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I ve tested this but every time I enter more and more elements the tableview is going on the bottom of the ios screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect bounds = [self.tableView bounds];
[self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(...)];
CGRect tableFrame = [ self.predictiveDialog frame];
tableFrame.size.height=75;
[self.tableView setFrame:tableFrame];
```

The code `[self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(...)]` is useless here since you finally set the frame of the tableView.

To avoid your tableView moving, you can use `tableFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.origin.y`.